# Modifying my php-mysql mechanism to include in the results a custom mutiple checkbox values

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP MySql query forming mechanism in order to process the data the user puts in the form and fetch the relative results from my database.

```
<?php
// build array of field names=============================================================================
$fields=array('user','customer','vessel','country',
             'port','eta','service_station',
             'case_reference','status');

// initialize empty array for WHERE clauses
$wheres=array();

// loop through field names, get POSTed values,
// and build array of WHERE clauses, excluding false values
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  // get existing field value from POST, mark missing or empty value as FALSE
  ${$field} = isset($_POST[$field]) && trim($_POST[$field])!=''
      ? trim($_POST[$field]) : false;

  // add to array of WHERE clauses only if value is not FALSE
  if (${$field}) { $wheres[]="$field LIKE '".${$field}."%'"; }

}

    $sql="SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE ".
         (!empty($wheres) ? implode(" AND ",$wheres) : '1=1').
         ";";
?>


<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <label name="user"><input/></label>
  <label name="customer"><input/></label>
  <label name="vessel"><input/></label>
  <label name="country"><input/></label>
  <label name="port"><input/></label>
  <label name="eta"><input/></label>
  <label name="service_station"><input/></label>
  <label name="case_reference"><input/></label>
  <label name="status"><input/></label>
</body>
```

I would like to add a column in my database called **type_of_service**. But in my search form i would like to add a list of checkboxes according to the the type of service so the user will be able to put more than one type at the same time:

```
<div id="multiselect" class="field">
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Fire Extinguishers">Fire Extinguishers</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Fixed CO2 Systems">Fixed CO2 Systems</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Fixed Foam Systems">Fixed Foam Systems</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Liferafts">Liferafts</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Lifeboats & Davits">Lifeboats & Davits</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Immersion Suits & Lifejackets">Immersion Suits & Lifejackets</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Breathing Apparatus">Breathing Apparatus</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Medical Oxygen Resuscitators">Medical Oxygen Resuscitators</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Emergency Escape Sets">Emergency Escape Sets</label></br>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="New Supply">New Supply</label></br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="type_of_service[]" value="Other">Other Equipment/Works</label>
    </div>        
  </div>
```

In what way should i modify my PHP MySQL query forming mechanism in order to include this and be ab;le to search through checkboxes as well???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a design problem. Of how is your data structured.

You have several options:

- You join your types with a comma or so (very ugly)
- You make for every option a column (very ugly)
- You make a seperate table for storing a type binded with a job_id. When retrieving the types you can search that table by `select type from job_types where job_id = 1` (best option)

You loop over the checkboxes and a a row to the `job_types` table with the coresponding `job_id`. Then you have your data well structured.

Comment: Can you please kindly suggest how joining my types with a comma would be structured inside my code? Because making a search engine involving two different tables is kind out of my league for now:(

Comment: I went with the seperate table solution after all thanks for your answer.